# custom thymeleaf dialect registration causing exception

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

in applicationContext.xml

```
 <bean id="templateEngine"
      class="org.thymeleaf.spring3.SpringTemplateEngine">
    <property name="templateResolver" ref="templateResolver" />
    <property name="additionalDialects">
        <set>
            <bean class="org.test.custom.CustomDialact" />
        </set>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Stacktrace:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'additionalDialects' of bean class [org.thymeleaf.spring3.SpringTemplateEngine]: Bean property 'additionalDialects' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:1042)
at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:902)
at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:75)
at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:57)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1424)
... 50 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i don't know but it was fixed after restarting machine. but mean while i find another solution
by extend a custom class with `HashSet` and in constructor add custom dialect in it and declare it in xml. provide it reference to `additionalDialects` . thats it .it will start running . it think it is problem related to generics as spring sometimes supply empty type 
like `HashSet<V>` .